# How do I get a div to expand when necessary, like a table does?

Tags: html, css

When I have a table with a width of 800px and an image within it with a width of 1000px, the table will expand to encompass the image. When I have a div with a width of 800px and the same image within it, the div will remain at 800px and the image will cross over the div's border. How do I get a div to replicate this expand-when-necessary nature of a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `width` to `auto` and the `min-width` to `800px` if you don't have to support IE6.

Like this

```
#mydiv {
    width:auto;
    min-width:800px;
}
```

Comment: When I do that, the div's width will be the page width, not 800px?

Comment: For IE6 support define another rule `* html #mydiv { width:800px; }` since only IE6 evaluates `* html` rules and treats `width` like `max-width`.